# Maintain HTTP Method Type while redirecting

Tags: http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, redirect

I have a problem while using .htaccess redirection:

```
    ....
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^GET
    RewriteRule ^retweet/(.*)$ /test.php?method=get&path=$1  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^PUT
    RewriteRule ^retweet/(.*)$ /test.php?method=put&path=$1  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^DELETE
    RewriteRule ^retweet/(.*)$ /test.php?method=delete&path=$1  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^POST
    RewriteRule ^retweet/(.*)$ /test.php?method=get&path=$1  
    RewriteRule ^retweet/(.*)$ /test.php?method=null&path=$1
```

In fact, in this way, I'll always obtain *null* as matched HTTP method catched through PHP. I've tried also to use this simpler solution:

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test.php?path=$1
```

But, in this way, it will always return the "GET" PHP method. Is there any solution? 
Thanks.

Comment: How's about making the redirect final with  `[L]` ?

Comment: not really a php question, removed php tag and added mod-rewrite tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
RewriteRule ^retweet/(.*) /test.php?method=%{REQUEST_METHOD}&path=$1
```